# Why is the property setter is not working properly?

Tags: python, properties

I am studying how properties/getters/setters work, but i can't make it work:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age=20):
        self.age = age

    def set_age(self, new_age):
        if new_age > 0 and new_age < 120:
            self.age = new_age

    age = property(set_age)

i=Person()
i.age = 21
```

Since `age` was given the property `set_age`, i should be able to use it to set age but i get an attribute error instead:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 11, in <module>
    i=Person()
    line 3, in __init__
    self.age = age
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I tried making `self.age` private in the `__init__` by renaming is `self._age` (dunno why, i saw many examples that used private attributes so decided to try) and still got an error, but not in the `__init__` anymore:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 12, in <module>
    i.age = 21
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

It's weird, the private naming is just a convention, but here it actually changes the amount of errors.

I thought that since property can have getters/setters/del/doc i had to specify it was a setter by changing it to:

```py
    age = property(fset=set_age)
```

But that gave a `RecursionError` error.

What would the problem be?

Edit: changed `&` by `and` and the problem continues.

Comment: There is an error in your set_age function: you've type '&' instead 'and'

Comment: Just changed it, still gives attribute error.

Comment: You can define that property with `age = property(fset=set_age)` and use `self._age` everywhere. The first argument is being assumed to be the `fget`. Of course, without an `fget`, you'll get attribute errors trying to read the value of the property: i.e. `print(i.age)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the name of the property, class properties and setter function inputs should be different. Also, you should implement a getter.
Working example:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age=20):
        self._age = age

    def set_age(self, new_age):
        print(new_age)
        if new_age > 0 and new_age < 120:
            self._age = new_age

    def get_age(self):
        return self._age

    age = property(get_age, set_age)

i=Person()
i.age = 21
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to test if i could use properties without a getter (to know if property() could automatically know that was going to be a setter) but it seems such thing is not possible? Property can lack a fdel or doc but it MUST have a getter before the setter?

Comment: @flonne you can use property without getter with `age = property(fset=set_age)`, the problem was the property name being the same as the method parameter